# NumPy 2D array: selecting indices in a circle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

For some rectangular we can select all indices in a 2D array very efficiently:

```
arr[y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

...where `(x, y)` is the upper-left corner of the rectangle and `height` and `width` the height (number of rows) and width (number of columns) of the rectangular selection.

Now, let's say we want to select all indices in a 2D array located in a certain circle given center coordinates `(cx, cy)` and radius `r`. Is there a numpy function to achieve this efficiently?

Currently I am pre-computing the indices manually by having a Python loop that adds indices into a buffer (list). Thus, this is pretty inefficent for large 2D arrays, since I need to queue up every integer lying in some circle.

```
# buffer for x & y indices
indices_x = list()
indices_y = list()

# lower and upper index range
x_lower, x_upper = int(max(cx-r, 0)), int(min(cx+r, arr.shape[1]-1))
y_lower, y_upper = int(max(cy-r, 0)), int(min(cy+r, arr.shape[0]-1))
range_x = range(x_lower, x_upper)
range_y = range(y_lower, y_upper)

# loop over all indices
for y, x in product(range_y, range_x):
    # check if point lies within radius r
    if (x-cx)**2 + (y-cy)**2 < r**2:
        indices_y.append(y)
        indices_x.append(x)

# circle indexing
arr[(indices_y, indices_x)]
```

As mentioned, this procedure gets quite inefficient for larger arrays / circles. Any ideas for speeding things up?

If there is a better way to index a circle, does this also apply for "arbitrary" 2D shapes? For example, could I somehow pass a function that expresses membership of points for an arbitrary shape to get the corresponding numpy indices of an array?

Comment: Is 'y' the upper left or the lower left ? Because if we add the height to upper left we would go over the boundary right ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could define a mask that contains the circle. Below, I have demonstrated it for a circle, but you could write any arbitrary function in the `mask` assignment. The field `mask` has the dimensions of `arr` and has the value `True` if the condition on the righthand side is satisfied, and `False` otherwise. This mask can be used in combination with the indexing operator to assign to only a selection of indices, as the line `arr[mask] = 123.` demonstrates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 32)
y = np.arange(0, 32)
arr = np.zeros((y.size, x.size))

cx = 12.
cy = 16.
r = 5.

# The two lines below could be merged, but I stored the mask
# for code clarity.
mask = (x[np.newaxis,:]-cx)**2 + (y[:,np.newaxis]-cy)**2 < r**2
arr[mask] = 123.

# This plot shows that only within the circle the value is set to 123.
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, arr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice work. I timed it on my computer and it was <= 5 times faster than my approach, while indicating that the difference gets larger for larger arrays (as expected, since Python loops get slower for very large number of iterations). However, could you explain `mask = (x[np.newaxis,:]-cx)**2 + (y[:,np.newaxis]-cy)**2 < r**2` in detail? Why exactly do we need/use `np.arange` for `x` and `y` as initial values? Btw: very nice idea to use `np.newaxis` this way to get an 2D array after addition.

Comment: I had to generate two coordinates `x` and `y` to be able to calculate a circle. You could use any function for that, `arange` was just a convenient choice for me.

Comment: @Chiel Could you explain what the 123 is ?

Comment: Just a random value to set the values in the mask to. Could have been `2384745` as well

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Chiel for your answer, but I couldn't see radius 5 in the output.(diameter is 9 in output and not 10)

One can **reduce .5** from **cx and cy** to produce diameter 10

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 32)
y = np.arange(0, 32)
arr = np.zeros((y.size, x.size))

cx = 12.-.5
cy = 16.-.5
r = 5.

# The two lines below could be merged, but I stored the mask
# for code clarity.
mask = (x[np.newaxis,:]-cx)**2 + (y[:,np.newaxis]-cy)**2 < r**2
arr[mask] = 123.

# This plot shows that only within the circle the value is set to 123.
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, arr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: difference]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31620437)